# prevent r's capture.output while being ''in it''?

Tags: r

I am using a complicated function in a package. This function accepts callback functions (defined by me) and crashes due to some weird reason. So I put a breakpoint into the callback function in order to see what is going wrong. However, whenever I want to see some output inside the callback function then I cannot see anything. The reason is that in the complicated function, the callback is called like this:

```
complicatedFunction = function(callBack) {
   utils::capture.output({
      callBack()
   })
}
```

Can I prevent or disable `utils::capture.output` while being ''in it''?

Cheers,

Fabian Werner

Comment: Just a guess, have you tried `capture.output` argument `type = "message"`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas: Good guess, silly me... you mean like `callBack = function() { capture.output(type="message");  print("aaa"); }`? Does not work... and neither does this: `capture.output({print("aaa")}, type="message")`

Comment: You could try `split=TRUE`, which should both store the output to file and return it. As a second possibility, you could turn it off temporarily to perform the debugging.